# Keeping selected images instead of replacing with the new ones

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, variables

I'm trying to create a HTML file input field which can add files (in this case images) multiple times, instead of replacing existing chosen files.

The file field will always replace the previous selection. What I am trying to do is store the selection somewhere else each time user selects a file.

```
$("#imageInput").change(function() {
    if(typeof window.images == "undefined"){
        window.images = this.files;
    }
    else {
        var k = 0;
        console.log(window.images.length); //always equals to this.files.length
        for (var i = window.images.length; i < window.images.length + this.files.length; i++) {
            window.images[i] = this.files[k];
            k++;
        }
    }
});
```

The HTML input tag:

```
<input type="file" id="imageInput" multiple accept="image/*">
```

This solutions doesn't work, because the `window.images` array is always reset when new files are choosen.

Comment: If you have trouble for storing your data, you could use the `localStorage` of your browser.

Comment: @FabienGreard  Howard does not want to use it across site !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indexOf :

> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the
>   search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

```js
  
     var images = [];
     var imagesName = [];
    $("#imageInput").change(function() {
       
        for(var i=0;i<this.files.length;i++)
        {  
              
             if(imagesName.indexOf(this.files[i].name)==-1)
             {
               console.log(this.files[i]);
               images.push(this.files[i]);
               imagesName.push(this.files[i].name);
             }
             
         }
        
        console.log(imagesName);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="imageInput" multiple accept="image/*">
```

Comment: I want the images to stay only that specific page, I don't need them globally

Comment: @HowardFring we cannot retain some files and add others. So you have to select all files together in on shot. modifying code for that.

Comment: I found a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. This works:

```
$("#imageInput").change(function() {
    var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.files);
    filesArr.forEach(function(f) {
        window.images.push(f);
    });
    console.log(window.images);
});
```

Comment: So you just want to continue adding files selected by user. This code can push same images again and again. It will not work if user selects a image multiple times

Comment: yeah, i have not handled that specific case with this code

Comment: but if you can, i'm listening

Comment: edited code, don't forget to upvote and accept answer, happy codings :)

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using `Array.concat()` to put all the new files on the end of the array:

```
window.images = [];
$("#imageInput").change(function() {
    window.images = window.images.concat(this.files);
});
```

If you're in ES6, you can use the spread operator and `Array.push()`:

```
window.images = [];
$("#imageInput").change(function() {
    window.images.push(...this.files);
});
```

...which has the advantage of keeping the same array object, just making it longer.

Comment: it's an image of the logging: first I added the img numb. 406 then 408 and then 410

Comment: Ah, I see - the problem is that as `this.files` changes, the contents of the array change.

Comment: it should store the img numb. 406, 408 and 410 instead of the 410 three times