# multiple file selection and processing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page where there is a button to select a HTML file, and once the file is selected, some treatment is applied to it in JavaScript. 
The code looks like this:

```
 document.querySelector("#file").addEventListener("change", function() {
        // Get filename from selected file
        var filename = this.value.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        console.log(filename);

readTextFile("output/".concat(filename), function(text) {
     // and then the actual solution is contained in this function readTextFile 
     });
});
```

I would like to be able to tweak this code to be able to apply the treatment to a batch of HTML files all at once. For instance, to all the HTML files in a given folder.

But I am new to JS and I honestly don't have a clue how I could do it.

Is there a way to have a multiple file selection buttons, so that I can apply the treatment to all the selected files?

Comment: You can use `<input type="file" name="img" multiple>` HTML

Comment: Then you can iterate over files by `this.files` in js and you can process them as you like

Comment: Refer my answer here  -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957698/keeping-selected-images-instead-of-replacing-with-the-new-ones/50957906#50957906